# Como funciona o router do angular?

Tags: angular

Bom dia, estou com duvida sobre o `router` do `angular2` para passar valores para outra página... Não sei como utilizar e nem como funciona, podem ajudar? Já vi vários exemplos em fóruns, porem mesmo assim ainda não entendi qual sua função em si, e como utiliza-lo...

Comment: Qual versão do Angular?

Comment: Como funciona é uma coisa bem ampla, talvez um exemplo ou um tutoria com esse ajude mais: https://rafaell-lycan.com/2015/angular-definindo-rotas/

Comment: Eu editei e coloquei a versão, desculpa xD

Comment: Essa pergunta e muito ampla. Pelo menos tente alguma coisa e poste algum codigo https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Comment: @EduardoVargas eu não tenho nenhum código sobre esse assunto, só queria alguma explicação básica para ter uma ideia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bruno, Existem várias formas de usar o router e passar parâmetro.

Através de rota do navegador:

No seu routing.module:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders} from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AgendaConfirmacaoComponent } from './agenda-confirmacao/agenda-confirmacao.component';


const agendaRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'agendaConfirm/:id',
    component: AgendaConfirmacaoComponent
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(agendaRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AgendaRoutingModule {}
```

Nesse trecho de código você configura o routing, falando qual vai ser a rota, e o :id indica que vai receber um parâmetro. Você está nesse momento apenas configurando uma rota que poderá ser usada.

No seu html ou no component.ts você em algum momento chama essa rota, vou te mostrar duas formas:

```
<a routerLink="/agenda/agendaConfirm" [queryParams]="{id_agendamento: vlb.id}">Abrir</a>
```

Veja que chamei o routerLink chamando a rota, e na queryParams eu estou enviando o id do agendamento nomeado para id_agendamento.

No componente.ts da minha página de confirmação de agenda eu recebo esse id dessa forma:

```
 this.route.queryParams.subscribe(
        (queryParams: any) => {
          this.id_agendamento = queryParams['id_agendamento'];
        });
```

Perceba que o nome usado no queryParams do routerLink é o mesmo que usei pra ler esse id no component.ts.

Outra forma de redirecionar para uma página passando parâmetro é da seguinte forma:

```
this.router.navigate(['/agenda/agendaConfirm', this.idAgendamento]);
```

Essa linha de código é uma outra alternativa para quando estiver em algum método no component.ts e for redirecionar para a página levando um parâmetro.

No component.ts a leitura será da seguinte forma, caso opte por usar o navigate:

```
id_agendamento = this.route.snapshot.params['id']; 
//o id usado no 'params['id']' é o mesmo que foi nomeado no routing:

const agendaRoutes: Routes = [
      {
        path: 'agendaConfirm/:id',
        component: AgendaConfirmacaoComponent
      },
]; //Essa foi a rota que definimos lá em cima usando agendaConfirm/:id
```

Espero ter ajudado,

Essas são as formas que mais utilizo.
Qualquer dúvida é só falar que tento clarear mais um pouco.

Comment: Pronto, deu para dar uma esclarecida melhor, obrigado!!